# Viewpager - multiple CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have Activity, that contains Viewpager. This ViewPager contains 2 Fragments. Every of this fragment contains CoordinatorLayout, CollapsingToolbarlayout, AppBarLayout, Toolbar and RecyclerView. If I scroll down in one recyclerView, is there any way, how could I programatically force to collapse the second CollapsingToolbarLayout depends on the first CollapsingToolbarLayout? I know, that there is the method addOnOffsetChangedListener for AppBarLayout, that will return me the ,,current" height of the Collapsed/Expanded layout, but there isn't any method for forcing partly collapsing/expanding the second CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding listeners between Fragments.In ViewPager there is some feature if you have 3 Fragments A, B, C and when you are in A Fragment , Fragment B's will be automatically initialized but not C one.If you swipe toward B then your C fragment will be initialized.